# My hibernate project doesnt work when i choose apache instead of glassfish

Tags: apache, hibernate, glassfish-3, netbeans-6.9

I am using netbeans 6.9.1 to develop a project using frameworks Hibernate 3.2.5 and JavaServer  Faces, i probably followed this tutorial

http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/hibernate-webapp.html

In this tutorial it uses GlassFish 3 to setup the project which i did as well and it works fine. But when i deployed it to my server on apache tomcat 7, it gives this error 
"Class DBws.DBws is not a Servlet"

I changed the server from glassfish to apache in netbeans and it started giving error in file on this location

```
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.model.DataModel;
import javax.faces.model.ListDataModel;
```

with a red line under javax, what to do now, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add jsf libraries in your WEB-INF/lib folder, 
libraries can be found [here](http://javaserverfaces.java.net/).

Glassfish by default has those libraries but I guess tom-cat doesn't.

Comment: thanks, that was helpful, but still im getting an error, when i run the webservice it says something like wsdl not found, could these libraries conflict with the existing libraries in apache? (other webservices are working fine)

Comment: Nope.. these libraries cannot cause wsdl issue.. must be other problem.